# macOS: how to create a view that is in front of EVERYTHING

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui, macos-big-sur

I'm developing a macOS application, and I want to create a View that is in front of EVERYTHING on the screen, like a screen saver that occludes everything on the screen.

`view.window?.level = .floating` is not what I want since the view cannot cover the menubar nor the Dock bar.

What I want is like the following picture (from the App named "Paste"), but I want the view to be fullscreen:

[image: popup window in the "Paste" App]

Comment: If the view is fullscreen, it's "above everything" by definition. The view is fullscreen if 1) the user wants so 2) you've managed to do it programmatically. So have you considered just entering fullscreen programmatically? While I don't know it's considered a good UX to force an app be fullscreen.

Comment: @Olha I'm developing a tool that reminds you to take a reset after a long focusing time, so I need it to occlude the things you are working on and force you to take a rest.

Comment: Just use `window.level = .screenSaver` or `window.level = .mainMenu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.level = .mainMenu + 1`. It worked for me.

Comment: Yes, but only use this is not sufficient. Set the styleMask to be empty like this `let window = NSWindow(contentRect: rect, styleMask: [], backing: .buffered, defer: false)`, and then set `window.level = .mainMenu + 1` works.

Comment: Neither this solution, nor the comment work for me. If I switch to another app, it disappears behind it